# Protected route doesn't work properly after refresh, useEffect problem

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm trying to protect routes by roles of user, almost everything works fine, but every time  I refresh current page, protected route always gives me no access, and by link to I can acces.
I know that It's something wrong with useEffect I don't know how can I make It works.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState();
  const [status, setStatus] = useState();

  useEffect(async () => {
    await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/user").then((res) => {
      setAuth(res.data);
      
    });
  }, [status]);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route element={<ProtectedRoleRoute role={auth?.user?.isAdmin} />}>
        <Route path="admin" element={<Admin />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="noauth" element={<NoAuth />} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

ProtectedRoleRoute

```
    function ProtectedRoleRoute(props) {
  return props?.role ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/noauth" replace />;
}

export default ProtectedRoleRoute;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you refresh the page your state does not persist. An option is to set the auth keyword in the localStorage.

in your useEffect

```
useEffect(async () => {
    await Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/user").then((res) => {
      setAuth(res.data);
      localstorage.setItem(auth, res.data.?user?.isAdmin);
      
    });
  }, [status]);
```

in your route use

```html
<Route element={<ProtectedRoleRoute role={localStorage.getItem('auth')} />}>
```